# javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am using spring version (4.2.1.RELEASE) AND Spring security version (4.0.3.RELEASE). Above exception is occurred because of the below code section.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have found that the reason for this exception is compatibility issues of the spring and spring security versions from following link

[HTTP Status 500 - Filter execution threw an exception - doFilter and invokeDelegate repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968752/http-status-500-filter-execution-threw-an-exception-dofilter-and-invokedeleg)

But that didn't work for me. Again I am using hibernate in this project. If i change the spring version then hibernate is occurred an error.

These are my dependencies

```
<spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
<security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</security.version>
<hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
<jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
<org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
<springsecurityoauth2.version>2.0.10.RELEASE</springsecurityoauth2.version>
```

Your help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Finally i could find the issue. The exception is thrown  because below code is run as a loop according to my opinion.

I changed this code to

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This solved my issue.